# How to identify webrtc decoding type of safari browser？

Tags: safari, webrtc

I want to know how to identify webrtc decoding type of safari browser？For example, H264, H265 etc...

Chrome has a webrtc tool "chrome://webrtc-internals/", while it didn't work in Safari. I also add debug menu to Safari, while I still can't run the webrtc log. Is there any solution to know the webrtc decoder of Safari browser on Mac and ios?

Answer (score 0):

chrome's webrtc-internals page uses the RTCPeerConncetion.getStats() API and provides (roughly) the same data. You can get the codecId
https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcrtpstreamstats-codecid
from the inbound-rtp statistics and then look up the codec statistics in the getStats result.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/change-codecs/ shows  a sample for the outbound codec.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helps a lot! I could print log on Mac Safari, but it is still not working on iOS, is it common? 
  
And I still have a question. Could you please tell me how to identify the codec type using the RTCPeerConncetion.getStats() API?

I have followed your direction and get the inbound-rtp statistics. But it seems not so clear whether the video is hardware accelerated or not.

The following comment presented the inbound-rtp statisticsis from Mac Safari.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Report: inbound-rtp
ID: RTCInboundRTPVideoStream_2351583795
Timestamp: 1667463822502
codecId: RTCCodec_1_Inbound_98
kind: video
mediaType: video
ssrc: 2351583795
transportId: RTCTransport_0_1
framesDropped: 0
jitter: 0
packetsLost: 0
packetsReceived: 11541
bytesReceived: 11007650
estimatedPlayoutTimestamp: 3876452622512
firCount: 0
frameHeight: 856
frameWidth: 480
framesDecoded: 3169
framesPerSecond: 30
framesReceived: 3169
headerBytesReceived: 323628
jitterBufferDelay: 132.255
jitterBufferEmittedCount: 3166
keyFramesDecoded: 1
lastPacketReceivedTimestamp: 1667463822469

Comment: Safari may not implement the decoderImplementation field for privacy reasons.